# awk - compare 2 files and use md5 function

Tags: linux, awk, hashsum

I need to hash each line of second file (md5) and compare it with the first file line by line like that :

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next}; !(md5($1) in a)' file1 file2 > file3
```

How can I do this using `awk`?

**file1:**

```
5ca4136a060a2574a936cdf6881f733c
8068123f8384b305d133add978a3c12c
```

**file2:**

```
aaa@aaa.com
ccc@ccc.com
```

and with this example :

```
5ca4136a060a2574a936cdf6881f733c = aaa@aaa.com
```

**output:**

```
ccc@ccc.com
```

Comment: Also, while you're there, explain the relevance of needing a comma as `awk`'s field separator.

Comment: hey, thank you for eply please check i edit my post (y)

Comment: plz any one can help me do that ?

Comment: You asked the question half an hour ago. Please give us some time.

Comment: So you want a file (or a line) in file2 which has no hash in file1?

Comment: @Kusalananda take your time ;)

Comment: @αғsнιη i have file1 contains emails hashed with md5, and file2 contains just emails , i need to compare hash code in file1 with email in file2 but i need to convert each line in file2 first, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{seen[$0];next}{x="echo " $0 "|md5sum| cut -d- -f1|cut -f1 ";
     x|getline l;close(x);md5[l]=$0} 
END{for (M in md5) {chk=md5[M];gsub (" ", "", M);for (U in seen) if(M==U){print M, chk}}
}' file1 file2
```

Inputs:

```
==> file1 <==
5ca4136a060a2574a936cdf6881f733c
8068123f8384b305d133add978a3c12c
96653200bf87722738bc4abf7b3d5589
731a1f0a260d40c758aa18237de3fe6c
```

```
==> file2 <==
aaa@aaa.com
ccc@ccc.com
UNIX.stackexchange.com
STACKECHANGE.COM
```

Output (those mail addresses that their hash was seen in file1):

```
731a1f0a260d40c758aa18237de3fe6c UNIX.stackexchange.com
96653200bf87722738bc4abf7b3d5589 ccc@ccc.com
```

---

With using `grep` that's a quite easy.

```
grep -Ff file1 \
    <(awk '{x="echo " $0 "|md5sum| cut -d- -f1"; x|getline l;print l, $0}' file2)

96653200bf87722738bc4abf7b3d5589   ccc@ccc.com
731a1f0a260d40c758aa18237de3fe6c   UNIX.stackexchange.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `join` and Perl for doing the MD5 computation, in `bash` or `ksh93`, or `zsh`:

```
$ join -v1 <( perl -MDigest::MD5 -ne 'chomp; printf("%s %s\n",Digest::MD5::md5_hex($_),$_)' text-file | sort ) \
           <( sort md5-file )
5a09ab8a3f03376046a6e6eec0a0d511 ccc@ccc.com
```

`join` is told to join the sorted MD5 hashes from the file with the mail addresses, with the ones found in the MD5 file, and to print every mismatched line from the address file.

The hash is printed too, but you may filter out that with `cut -d ' ' -f 2-`:

```
$ join -v1 <( perl -MDigest::MD5 -ne 'chomp; printf("%s %s\n",Digest::MD5::md5_hex($_),$_)' text-file | sort ) \
           <( sort md5-file ) | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
ccc@ccc.com
```

The output from the Perl code is on the form

```
5ca4136a060a2574a936cdf6881f733c aaa@aaa.com
5a09ab8a3f03376046a6e6eec0a0d511 ccc@ccc.com
```

and this is what's sorted and given to `join`.  The join will happen on the first space-delimited field by default.